# scrapy is not working with youtube search query ? returns 404

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to search on youtube given queries and fetching video information from youtube with scrapy but somehow when I make spider write start_urls something like this:

start_urls = [
   ........,
   'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=web+development',
   .........,
]

it says forbidden by robot.txt and returns response 404 and when I run the command scrapy shell url= from outside of project it returns response 200 and same command (scrapy shell url) returns 404 from inside of project. how can I make my spider work for this? what headers or something else do I need to add? Thank you so much in advance

here is the code and log:

```
import scrapy

class YoutubeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'youtube'
    allowed_domains = ['youtube.com']
    start_urls = [
        "http://youtube.com/results?search_query=web+development"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):   print('*************success*******************************************')
        print(self.start_urls)




    2019-09-07 18:43:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: emailExtractor)
2019-09-07 18:43:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
2019-09-07 18:43:15 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'emailExtractor', 'LOG_FILE': 'D:/log.txt', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'emailExtractor.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['emailExtractor.spiders']}
2019-09-07 18:43:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 7d4ad6d6005e1b68
2019-09-07 18:43:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-09-07 18:43:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-09-07 18:43:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.youtube.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-09-07 18:43:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=web+development>
2019-09-07 18:43:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-09-07 18:43:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 224,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 679,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.585362,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 7, 13, 13, 17, 679025),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/forbidden': 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 7, 13, 13, 16, 93663)}
2019-09-07 18:43:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Why not use the youtube api itself? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: I am working on crawler which will crawl youtube. something like software for my project of college so API won't work.

Comment: show us full spider code and also spider logs

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=robots#robotstxt-obey

Answer (score 2):

By default Scrapy will respect `robots.txt` policies (see the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#robotstxt-obey)).
To change this behavior, set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` in the `settings.py` file of your project to `False`.

Comment: What is strange is in the shell it gives no problem without set `-s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False`. I tested it from my shell, it has no problem, and the "directory" `/results` is not disallowed in robots.txt policy of Youtube. So I hope it is a solution for this person, but it does not seem to be the root of the issue.

Comment: I think it is because scrapy shell command or other command which you are using is global and documentation says that these command might work slightly different when work from inside project. the exact words  of documentation :  "There are two kinds of commands, those that only work from inside a Scrapy project (Project-specific commands) and those that also work without an active Scrapy project (Global commands), though they may behave slightly different when running from inside a project (as they would use the project overridden settings)."

Comment: thanks to the answer given and help of documentation I have solved the problem by changing setting. Thank you so much.

Comment: @FaizanSyed I have never encountered a situation where Scrapy had different behaviors with these types of commands, global commands are used to interact with the library or some spider outside a project, while project-specific commands are only used to interact with a project.

Comment: @FaizanSyed Can you clarify what changes you have made to the settings?

Comment: ArKan sorry for late answer I just came to know about your comment. I just added one command to the setting. that is : ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False